# how to simulate log on to a server programatically to use windows authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-authentication

I want to connect to the SQL SERVER and Analysing Server that are using windows authentication. There is no domain in the system so I want to do it by programatically simulating logging on the server with the login and password of the administrator of the server

Comment: Maybe you could just add SQL authentication to the SQL server? That's kind of what it's for... More importantly, windows authentication is there to get around having to write a password in a config in the first place - you're just shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: I cant do this for Analysing Service, its supports only windows authentication

Answer (score 1):

You need the Net use command to log onto a remote server.

Try this:

```
NET USE \\DBSERVER /USER:DOMAIN\USERNAME
```

You will be prompted for your password. This establishes a NetBIOS session with the database server. You should be able to see the shared folders and shared printers on the database server once you have done that.

Once that is successful, you should be able to specify "Integrated Authentication" to connect to the server.

To do this programmatically from C#, use the `NetUseAdd` function.